# Is it possible to set a Facebook group for people of only one country?

Tags: facebook-groups

In Facebook pages you can set the audience for people of the countries you want IIRC. I have a Facebook buy-sell group and people from another continent with a different alphabet continuously send membership requests to join. Obviously this people isnt interested in buying or selling anything in the region of the country my group is for, but they massively add groups with applications for sending spam links about whatever. Is it possible to set a Facebook group for people of only one country?